# "Error: Invalid count argument" error when trying to find the routing table' s id from the subnet ids to add new route entries

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, terraform

I am trying to update the routing tables of the subnets in VPC A and VPC B to include a route to a VPC peering end-point.   This is my terraform code.

**main.tf**

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 3.14.2"
  
  for_each = local.vpc_list
  name = each.key
  cidr =each.value.vpc_cidr
  azs = each.value.vpc_azs
  public_subnets  = each.value.vpc_public_subnets
  private_subnets = each.value.vpc_private_subnets
  enable_nat_gateway = each.value.vpc_enable_nat_gateway
  enable_vpn_gateway = each.value.vpc_enable_vpn_gateway
  tags = each.value.vpc_tags
  public_subnet_tags = each.value.vpc_public_subnet_tags
  private_subnet_tags = each.value.vpc_private_subnet_tags
}


resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "vpc_peering_conn" {

  peer_owner_id = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
  peer_vpc_id   = module.vpc["vpcB"].vpc_id
  vpc_id        = module.vpc["vpcA"].vpc_id
  auto_accept   = true

  tags = {
    Name = "VPC Peering between ${module.vpc["vpcA"].name} and ${module.vpc["vpcB"].name}."
  }
}


data "aws_route_tables" "vpcA_public_subnet_rts" {
  depends_on = [ module.vpc ]
  vpc_id = module.vpc["vpcA"].vpc_id

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Subnet"
    values = ["*public*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "route_vpcA" {
  count                     = length(data.aws_route_tables.vpcA_public_subnet_rts.ids)
  route_table_id            = tolist(data.aws_route_tables.vpcA_public_subnet_rts.ids)[count.index]
  destination_cidr_block    = "10.10.11.0/24"
  vpc_peering_connection_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.vpc_peering_conn.id
}


data "aws_route_tables" "vpcB_private_subnet_rts" {
  depends_on = [ module.vpc ]
  vpc_id = module.vpc["vpcB"].vpc_id

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Subnet"
    values = ["*private*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "route_vpcB" {
  count                     = length(data.aws_route_tables.vpcB_private_subnet_rts.ids)
  route_table_id            = tolist(data.aws_route_tables.vpcB_private_subnet_rts.ids)[count.index]
  destination_cidr_block    = "10.10.10.0/24"
  vpc_peering_connection_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.vpc_peering_conn.id
}
```

**locals.tf**

```
locals {
   vpc_list = {
   "vpcA" = { 
       vpc_cidr = "10.10.10.0/24", 
       vpc_azs             = ["ap-southeast-1a"],
       vpc_public_subnets  = ["10.10.10.0/25"], 
       vpc_private_subnets = ["10.10.10.128/25"],
       vpc_enable_nat_gateway = false, 
       vpc_enable_vpn_gateway = false,
       vpc_tags = {
           Name= "VPC A"
           Terraform = "true"
           Environment = "1st VPC"
           Facing= "public and private"
           },
       vpc_public_subnet_tags = {
            Subnet = "vpcA_public_subnet"
            },
       vpc_private_subnet_tags = {
            Subnet = "vpcA_private_subnet"
            },
        },
   "vpcB" = {
        vpc_cidr = "10.10.11.0/24", 
        vpc_azs             = ["ap-southeast-1b"],
        vpc_public_subnets  = [],
        vpc_private_subnets = ["10.10.11.0/24"], 
        vpc_enable_nat_gateway = false, 
        vpc_enable_vpn_gateway = false,
        vpc_tags = {
           Name= "VPC B"
           Terraform = "true"
           Environment = "2nd VPC"
           Facing= "private"
           },
        vpc_public_subnet_tags = {
            Subnet = "vpcB_public_subnet"
           },
        vpc_private_subnet_tags = {
            Subnet = "vpcB_private_subnet"
           },
        },
   }
}


locals {
  routing_table = {
    route_peer_con_vpcA = {
      vpc_id = module.vpc["vpcA"].vpc_id
      route = {
          route_peer_to_vpcB = {
            cidr_block        = "10.10.11.0/24"
          }  
      }
    }      
    route_peer_con_vpcB = {
      vpc_id = module.vpc["vpcB"].vpc_id
      route = {
           route_peer_to_vpcA = {
            cidr_block        = "10.10.10.0/24"
           } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the terraform plan or apply I am getting the below error.  Does anyone knows how to address the issue or Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

I saw this post "terraform: data.aws_subnet, value of 'count' cannot be computed" but am not sure how to refer to the output of the subnet' s id for the routing table id.

Thanks.

```
➜  01-tf-deploy terraform apply --auto-approve
data.aws_region.current: Reading...
data.aws_caller_identity.current: Reading...
data.aws_region.current: Read complete after 0s [id=ap-southeast-1]
data.aws_ami.amzlinux2: Reading...
data.aws_ami.amzlinux2: Read complete after 1s [id=ami-0c802847a7dd848c0]
data.aws_caller_identity.current: Read complete after 1s [id=500295128231]
╷
│ Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on main.tf line 70, in resource "aws_route" "route_vpcA":
│   70:   count                     = length(data.aws_route_tables.vpcA_public_subnet_rts.ids)
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count
│ depends on.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on main.tf line 88, in resource "aws_route" "route_vpcB":
│   88:   count                     = length(data.aws_route_tables.vpcB_private_subnet_rts.ids)
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count
│ depends on.
╵
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding the `data.aws_route_tables.vpcA_public_subnet_rts.ids` to the `locals` block and using that instead of the data source, something like `subnets = data.aws_route_tables.vpcA_public_subnet_rts.ids` and then `count = length(local.subnets)`.